# Creating a product with arduino bootloader

Tags: bootloader

If you have a prototype with arduino and you wish to create a real product can you do it or the fact that it contains the arduino bootloader prevents you?

BTW, i dont have a product ready. I am thinking options though. Or maybe i will have to go find a job

Comment: screw a job, i'm making a product right now :)

Comment: but srsly, a one millisecond google search found this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=104149.0

Comment: Getting a programmer means never having to worry about the bootloader. Unless you want it field-upgradeable, in which case you probably want one of the encrypted bootloaders Atmel provides anyways.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search found [this info on the Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=104149.0) which a user kindly shows the rules relating to this stuff.

The Optiboot bootloader is not actually an Arduino 'product'. Boards you design and software you write using Arduino IDE and libraries does not need to be disclosed to anybody, other than having the objects available (probably in a hidden part of your product's support website, in a "firmware" sub section) for some reason relating to being able to build the source against newer versions of Arduino.

I am currently making a product which I intend to use Arduino libraries and IDE and bootloader for fast development, but the board, schematics, and essentially the application code except for the libraries from Arduino will be mine. If you copy or build stuff specifically for/from Arduino hardware, you must(?) release certain source/schematics etc.